# Get data from table and echo in view

Tags: php

```
class Content {
    const mTable = "makes";

    public function getMakes($paginate = true) {
        if ($paginate) {
        $pager = Paginator::instance();
        $pager->items_total = countEntries(self::mTable);
        $pager->default_ipp = Registry::get("Core")->ipp;
        $pager->paginate();
        $limit = $pager->limit;
    } else {
        $limit = null;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . self::mTable . " ORDER BY name" . $limit;
    $row = self::$db->fetch_all($sql);

    return ($row) ? $row : 0;
    }  
}
```

i have this line of code, i am confused to how to get data from makes table in foreach loop.

any suggestion would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: which database are you using? what does `var_dump($row);` output?

Comment: As @Bhargav says `var_dump($row)` or `print_r($row)` will help - I'm guessing it's probably similar to the PDO method [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use * because once you make changes to your table, you will create problems in your code. Just try print_r($row) and adjust your $row[] based on the keys outputted in your print.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, where $arr is the array of your objects, which were fetched via the query:

```
 <?php
     $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
     echo "<table border=1>";
     echo "<tr><th>First title</th></tr>";
     foreach($arr as $i) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $i . "</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just do simply my function static

public static function getMakes()

```
foreach(Content::getMakes() as $model){  
    echo $model->name;  }
```